# Disabling child scaling, when parent scales with Math

Tags: c#, unity3d

I think this code is only simple math, but I'm posting it, because almost everyone fakes the scaling with unparenting, then parenting again.

```
Vector3 originalParentScale = new Vector3;
Vector3 originalScale = new Vector3;
void Awake(){
    originalScale = transform.localScale;
    originalParentScale = transform.parent.localScale;
}
void Update(){
    transform.localScale = (originalParentScale / transform.parent.localScale) * originalScale;
}
```

I think it can be even improved, so I would be happy if someone can improve it. It's challenge too, so happy programming :-)

Comment: There is one division and one multiplication... how do you want to improve it? Maybe by using integrals? ;-P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Unity3D, but are you absolutely 100% certain that `transform.parent.localScale` will never be 0? Otherwise, you should check for that before dividing.

Comment: Nothing in Unity3D prevents you from setting the localScale to (0, 0, 0)